# ReCaptcha mute help and refresh buttons diplaying incorrect

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I have been looking for overriding styles in the following captcha ->

```
http://54.216.85.81/login
```

as you will see the help, refresh and mute button have spacing inbetween, ideally the last two should be moved up the page 5px.

I have tried using negative margins to push them up which works for the first two but when I apply the margin to the last icon it makes all of them worse than when I started. :S

Thanks

Rick

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
img#recaptcha_whatsthis {
    margin-top: -10px !important;
}
```